# Creat a new list by grouping a property in c#

Tags: c#

I have following

```
class public class Pages
{

    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public string PageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PageMaster 
{

    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public Pages[] Pages{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a array of "PageMaster" from an array of Pages which contains repeating "Name" in it. i.e "Name" in  Pages is the "AppName" in PageMaster

Comment: Post the code which you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make use of [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var pageMasters = listOfPages.GroupBy(page=>page.PageName)
                             .Select(gr=>new PageMaster
                             { 
                                 AppName = gr.Key,
                                 Pages = gr.Select(p=>p).ToArray()
                             })
                             .ToList();
```